# Prove that $|r-\mu|\le \sigma\sqrt{2}$

Tags: probability

Let $r$ be the median of a random variable $X$. Let $\mathbb{E}X = \mu <\infty$ and $D^2 (X)=\sigma^2<\infty$.

Prove that $|r-\mu|\le \sigma\sqrt{2}$.

---

Obviously $\mathbb{P}(X\ge r)=\mathbb{P}(X\le r)\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

Any hint please?

**Edit 1:**

So I have $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|\ge\sqrt{2}\sigma)\le\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(|X-\mu|<\sqrt{2}\sigma)\ge\frac{1}{2}$. For $X=r$ the desired inequality holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Use the [Chebyshev Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_inequality) with $k=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Please check my edited post.

Comment: Minor point, we want $\Pr(|X-\mu|\lt \sqrt{2}\,\sigma)\ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @luka5z Sorry for being a slow but I don't see how your edit leads to a solution. Can you (or André) please elaborate?

Comment: @yurnero:  By definition $\Pr(X\ge r)\le 1/2$. But $\Pr(X\ge r)=\Pr(X-\mu\gt r-\mu)\le \Pr(|X-\mu|\ge |r-\mu|)$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas it seems you meant $\Pr(X\geq r)\geq\frac{1}{2}$; in any case, then we are not really using the fact that $r$ is the median, merely the fact that $\Pr(X\geq r)\geq\frac{1}{2}$.